# hook at AcceptEx retrieve remote connection ip

Tags: delphi, winsock

i'm hooking AcceptEx.
how i can retrieve remote connection ip from socket? since getpeername don't show right ip.

```
function GetRemoteSocketAddress ( s : TSocket ) : String;
var
  Addr                  : TSockAddrIn;
  Size: integer;
begin
  Size := sizeof(Addr);
  getpeername(s, Addr, Size);
  Result := inet_ntoa(Addr.sin_addr);
end;
```

this code works fine for others APIS like Send, Connect, Recv, all return right ip but not with AcceptEx.

```
function AcceptExHookProc(sListenSocket, sAcceptSocket: TSocket;
  lpOutputBuffer: Pointer; dwReceiveDataLength, dwLocalAddressLength,
  dwRemoteAddressLength: DWORD; var lpdwBytesReceived: DWORD;
  lpOverlapped: POverlapped): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  WriteLn(Format('[%s] Connection from IP (%s)', [TimeToStr(Now), GetRemoteSocketAddress(sAcceptSocket)]));
  Result := TrampolineAcceptEx(sListenSocket, sAcceptSocket, lpOutputBuffer,
    dwReceiveDataLength, dwLocalAddressLength, dwRemoteAddressLength, lpdwBytesReceived,
    lpOverlapped);
end;
```

tried sAcceptSocket or sListenSocket both show wrong ip.
tried retrieve ip before result, after result, always same wrong ip.

any idea?

Comment: On a side note, your `GetRemoteSocketAddress()` function only supports `AF_INET` (IPv4) sockets, it will fail on `AF_INET6` (IPv6) sockets.

Answer (score 0):

### You are calling `getpeername()` too soon.

You are calling `getpeername()` before you call the original `AcceptEx()`, so there is no socket connection established yet on which to query the remote party. You can't call `getpeername()` until after `AcceptEx()` is successful. This is even stated as much in the [`AcceptEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsock/nf-mswsock-acceptex) documentation:

> Using a single buffer improves performance. **When using `AcceptEx`, the `GetAcceptExSockaddrs` function must be called to parse the buffer into its three distinct parts (data, local socket address, and remote socket address).** On Windows XP and later, once the `AcceptEx` function completes and the `SO_UPDATE_ACCEPT_CONTEXT` option is set on the accepted socket, the local address associated with the accepted socket can also be retrieved using the `getsockname` function. **Likewise, the remote address associated with the accepted socket can be retrieved using the `getpeername` function.**

So, you must call `AcceptEx()` first, wait for it to complete successfully, then set the `SO_UPDATE_ACCEPT_CONTEXT` state via `setsockopt()` (which the program calling `AcceptEx()` should handle, don't set that state inside your hook code, unless you are also hooking `setsockopt()` itself), and only then can you use `getpeerename()` on the accepted connection.

A better option is to have your `AcceptExHookProc()` call the original `GetAcceptExSockaddrs()` immediately after `TrampolineAcceptEx()` exits (if successful) to parse the `lpOutputBuffer` contents.  But, that will only work if the `lpOverlapped` parameter is `nil` so `AcceptEx()` acts synchronously.

If `lpOverlapped` is not `nil`, so `AcceptEx()` acts asynchronously, you would have to hook [`GetAcceptExSockaddrs()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsock/nf-mswsock-getacceptexsockaddrs) and log the result of the original function parsing the caller's buffer.  But, there is no guarantee the program will actually call `GetAcceptExSockaddrs()` after `AcceptEx()`, if it doesn't want the remote party info.  In which case, you would have to resort to hooking into `GetOverlappedResult/Ex()` and/or `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` to receive the original `lpOverlapped` operation result in order to then call `GetAcceptExSockaddrs()` yourself if the operation is successful.

Comment: i called GetAcceptExSockaddrs before TrampolineAcceptEx and now return right ip, but i see connection is stabilished. and i'm trying prevent connection from some ips.

Comment: You must call `GetAcceptExSockaddrs()` AFTER calling `TrampolineAcceptEx()`, because `sAcceptSocket` is NOT CONNECTED YET until `AcceptEx()` is finished with its work.

Comment: "*i'm trying prevent connection from some ips*" - the best way to handle that is to use [`WSAAccept()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaaccept) instead, so you can provide a callback function that returns `CF_REJECT` for unwanted IPs before they leave the backlog queue. Using `accept()`/`AcceptEx()`, you can't reject IPs from the queue, all you can do is accept the connections and then immediately close them.

Comment: Already checked WSAAccept, program don't use it. only use AcceptEx. it's a .dll who i hooked at external program.

Comment: "accept the connections and then immediately close them." calling closesocket at sListenSocket, or sAcceptSocket make program stop receiving connections.

Comment: That is because 1) `sListenSocket` is the wrong socket to close, and 2) you have to close `sAcceptSocket` using [`DisconnectEx(TF_REUSE_SOCKET)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms737757(v=vs.85)) instead of `closesocket()` so the caller can re-use the same `SOCKET` for a future call to `AcceptEx()`.

Comment: LPFN_DISCONNECTEX(sAcceptSocket, lpOverlapped, TF_REUSE_SOCKET, 0);   are that right? 

LPFN_DISCONNECTEX : function(const hSocket : TSocket; AOverlapped:
  POverlapped; const dwFlags : DWORD; const dwReserved : DWORD) : BOOL; stdcall;

Comment: No, not right. Did you read the documentation? "*The function pointer for the `DisconnectEx` function must be obtained at run time by making a call to the [`WSAIoctl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741621(v=vs.85)) function with the `SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER` opcode specified. The input buffer passed to the `WSAIoctl` function must contain `WSAID_DISCONNECTEX`, a globally unique identifier (GUID) whose value identifies the `DisconnectEx` extension function. On success, the output returned by the `WSAIoctl` function contains a pointer to the `DisconnectEx` function.*"

Comment: Just like you have to do with `AcceptEx()`, `GetAcceptExSockaddrs()`, etc as well.

Comment: don't know how do it sorry, it's why i'm asking for help.

Comment: <sigh> We are getting off track from the original question. Consider posting a new question. But, try something like this: `const WSAID_DISCONNECTEX: TGuid = '{7fda2e11-8630-436f-a031-f536a6eec157}'; var lpDisconnectEx: LPFN_DISCONNECTEX; BytesOut: DWORD; ... WSAIoctl(sListenSocket, SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER, @WSAID_DISCONNECTEX, SizeOf(WSAID_DISCONNECTEX), @lpDisconnectEx, SizeOf(lpDisconnectEx), @BytesOut, nil, nil);`

Comment: And then you can call `lpDisconnectEx()` when needed, ie in `AcceptExHookProc()`: `if lpOverlapped <> nil then begin WSASetLastError(WSAEOPNOTSUPP); Result := False; Exit; end; repeat Result := TrampolineAcceptEx(..., sAcceptSocket, ...); if (not Result) then Exit; { get remote ip... } if (ip is not blocked) then Exit;  lpDisconnectEx(sAcceptSocket, nil, TF_REUSE_SOCKET, 0); until False;`

Comment: E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'WSAIoctl' and E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER'

Comment: @LuizFelipe obviously, you need to either add the relevant Winsock unit to your `uses` clause, or else declare your own `external` and const` declarations in your own code. But again, they is way out of scope of the original question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
    var
      IP            : String;
      LRet, RRet    : Winsock.PSockAddr;
      lsize, rsize  : Integer;
    begin
          Result := TrampolineAcceptEx(sListenSocket, sAcceptSocket, lpOutputBuffer,
    dwReceiveDataLength, dwLocalAddressLength, dwRemoteAddressLength, lpdwBytesReceived,
    lpOverlapped);

          lsize   := 32;
          rsize   := 32;
          Winsock.GetAcceptExSockaddrs(lpOutputBuffer, dwReceiveDataLength, dwLocalAddressLength, dwRemoteAddressLength, LRet, lsize, RRet, rsize);
        
          IP := Winsock.inet_ntoa(RRet.sin_addr);
        
          WriteLn(Format('[%s] Connection from IP (%s)', [TimeToStr(Now), IP]));
```